# Keep footer on every page

Tags: tumblr

I'm trying to keep my footer at the bottom of every page (not sticky). At the moment it is hovering in the middle of the screen.

Here is [my site](http://tinyurl.com/oy5r287).

And here is the code I have at the moment -

**HTML -**

```
<footer id="footer">
<a class="right">All Rights Reserved © 1-800 Dinosaur 2014 </a> 
</div>
</footer> <!-- footer --->
```

**CSS -**

```
#footer {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
background: transparent;
bottom: 0;
color: #444444;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 600;
height: 100px;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 44px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
#footer a {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
background: transparent;
bottom: 0;
color: #FFFFFF;
height: 100px;
left: 0;
padding: 44px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
#footer a:hover {
color: #000000;
}
#footer a:active {
background: transparent;
}
#footer .last-page {
text-align: center;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, absolute positioning has only worked if it was only in a parent specified to have relative positioning. Try putting your footer in a div with style="position: relative;" and see if that works. It actually looks like you've included a closing div tag without an open one in your snippet.

Comment: I originally tried 'position: relative;' and it moved it further up the page

Comment: Try getting rid of position absolute, and put the footer at the base of this container <div class="col-lg-12 goright"> I think the page height is calculated dynamically based on posts, so the footer positioning is correct at runtime, but not after the content has loaded (a bit of a guess)